# .NET Option CompareTo

Tags: .net, vb.net

I know in .NET that Objects can implement the Comparator and Comparable interfaces and then override compare and compareto.

How does Option Compare fit into this? I know that Option Compare allows Strings to be compared using a text method or a binary method. Are these different implementations of a Comparator?

Answer (score 3):

`Option Compare Text` comes from the original non-.NET VB. It's there for compatibility and/or convenience of VBx users, but it doesn't really belong the .NET framework paradigm where you can provide a comparer when you need to.

It only affects direct string comparisons done in your code, such as applying operators `=`, `<>`, `<` or `>` to variables and literals of type `String`. It does not override any Comparable interfaces, and the `String` class doesn't have any anyway.

I personally prefer to not mix the paradigms, and as such don't use `Option Compare Text` at all. When I need a case-insensitive comparison, I use [`String.Compare(s1, s2, True)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx), and when I need to provide a case-insensitive comparer to a function, I pass [`StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase.aspx).

Comment: +1, What happens if you use operator overloading? It is legal in .NET but illegal in Java, I believe.

Comment: @w0051977 Can you actually overload `operator =` for the `String` class? I don't think you can. And if you overload an operator for a class of yours, one member of which is a `String`, then comparing this `String` member to another string within the overloaded operator will be governed by `Option Compare`.

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0k7484c(v=vs.100).aspx

Option(Explicit|Strict|Compare|Infer) are to let the compiler know what flags to set when turning VB.NET code into an executable (they determine how the compiler interprets what you are trying to do with your code e.g. Option Compare toggles text (case insensitive) or binary (case sensitive) comparison for string operations). They don't have anything to do with the .NET Framework constructs and define how VB.NET code should be interpreted by other .NET languages like C# or F#.